# what is the smallest possible value of the other number

Tags: least-common-multiple

This seems to be a simple problem, but I stuck in the middle. I started with the formula $(a,b)[a,b] = ab$, and got $(a, 60)1260 = 60a$, which is $12(a,60)=a$. Then what should I do?

> The least common multiple (LCM) of two positive integers is 1260. If one of the numbers is 60, what is the smallest possible value of the other number?

Comment: The answer is 63.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$1260=2^2\cdot 3^2 \cdot 5 \cdot 7$$

$$60=2^2\cdot 3 \cdot 5$$
Therefore we need the smallest number divisible by seven and nine, which is $7\cdot9=63$.

Comment: Other numbers with a $LCM$ of $1260$ when paired with $60$ are $7\cdot9\cdot2$, $7\cdot9\cdot2^2$, $7\cdot9\cdot2^2\cdot5$, etc. However, $7\cdot9$ is the smallest of the solutions because it introduces no new factors.